# I am trying to pass user id from my blade template to Vue for Axios post request to the server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-blade

However when I click the button only the first button contains the user id the rest returns null. Also depending on where I place my id tag on HTML the `data-id` is empty. How can I pass data from my blade view to Vue.js for an Axios post request which contains the post Id ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#like',
  data: {
    post_id: '',
  },

  methods: {
    whichId: function(event) {
      this.post_id = this.$el.getAttribute('data-id');
      console.log(this.$el.getAttribute('data-id'));
    }
  }
})
```

```vue
<div class="container" id="like">
  <table class="table mt-5">
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($posts as $post)
      <tr>
        <td><img src="images/profil.svg" class="rounded-circle border border-dark ml-2" width="60" height="60" alt=""></td>
        <td>{{ $post->username->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $post->content }}</td>
        <td>
          <button v-on:click="whichId" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">
            <img src="/images/heart.svg" width="30" height="30" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using props to pass the ID? Also, forgot to mention - IDs are for unique elements, meaning - there should only be one element with given ID. You should use class for multiple instances.

Comment: @JCode Can't I pass data without creating a component ?

Comment: You can (I think) - just declare props first.

Answer (score 0):

The `this.$el` is going to refer to the  element. When using PHP to iterate through records. You should pass the id through the click event handler. Thanks to Wilk Randall on laracast for the help.

```js
methods: {
    whichId (postId) {
          console.log(postId);
    }
}
```

```html
<td><button v-on:click="whichId({{ $post->id }})"<img src="/images/heart.svg" width="30"></button></td>
```